# Categorize list in Python

Tags: python, list

What is the best way to categorize a list in python?

for example:

```
totalist is below

totalist[1] = ['A','B','C','D','E']
totalist[2] = ['A','B','X','Y','Z']
totalist[3] = ['A','F','T','U','V']
totalist[4] = ['A','F','M','N','O']
```

Say I want to get the list where the first two items are `['A','B']`, basically `list[1]` and `list[2]`.  Is there an easy way to get these without iterate one item at a time?  Like something like this?

```
if ['A','B'] in totalist
```

I know that doesn't work.

Comment: What is the code that you tried?

Comment: There is no way to solve this without iterating through it in some form as the answers suggest. You should remake how you represent the data if checking this efficiently is a big priority; sacrifice some space complexity for improved speed. You could, for example, when creating the list, in place note which rows satisfy the property.

Answer (score 3):

You could check the first two elements of each list.

```
for totalist in all_lists:
    if totalist[:2] == ['A', 'B']:
        # Do something.
```

**Note:** The one-liner solutions suggested by Kasramvd are quite nice too. I found my solution more readable. Though I should say comprehensions are slightly faster than regular for loops. (Which I tested myself.)

Comment: This should work great, not sure why you got a downvote, but I countered it for you.

Comment: @bravosierra99 Thank you, OP asked for a solution if there is a one which you dont have to iterate through the elements, perhaps that's why I got a downvote. But I don't see a way that we can achieve this without looping through all lists.

Comment: I assume he meant without looping through every individual item in every list.  You have to iterate through the lists or you can't check each one....

Comment: @bravosierra99 That's what I understood too.

Comment: Why over complicate things. If simple does it, use simple every time. It makes life easier for anyone who reads it or has to amend it, in the future.

Comment: The purpose is to give every possible(and plausible) solution to the OP, I also mentioned the pros and cons of this solution to my knowledge. Other solutions which I did not give, are given by other users.

Comment: Did you misunderstand my comment? It was praise that went with an up vote for your answer.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony It seems I totally misunderstood you comment. Sorry for the misinterpretation :)

Comment: Thanks, that if statement is what im looking for.  I basically have thousands of paths (in a list form) and trying to categorize them.  Seeing what branch the path belongs to.  Kind of like a tree structure

Comment: @user1179317 If you are trying to categorize all of the lists, you should take a look at `groupby`. You could use it with the key `lambda x: x[:2]`.

Comment: @Rockybilly: Or keyed on `operator.itemgetter(slice(2))` to reduce Python layer work. You'd need to sort though; `itertools.groupby` is like `uniq`; it only collapses adjacent elements. So something like `prefixkey = operator.itemgetter(slice(2))`, then `for prefix, grp in groupby(sorted(totalist, key=prefixkey), key=prefixkey):`

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, `itertools` solution to push per-element work to the C layer:

```
from future_builtins import map  # Py2 only; not needed on Py3
from itertools import compress
from operator import itemgetter

# Generator
prefixes = map(itemgetter(slice(2)), totalist)
selectors = map(['A','B'].__eq__, prefixes)

# If you need them one at a time, just skip list wrapping and iterate
# compress output directly
matches = list(compress(totalist, selectors))
```

This could all be one-lined to:

```
matches = list(compress(totalist, map(['A','B'].__eq__, map(itemgetter(slice(2)), totalist))))
```

but I wouldn't recommend it. Incidentally, if `totalist` might be a generator, not a re-iterable sequence, you'd want to use `itertools.tee` to double it, adding:

```
 totalist, forselection = itertools.tee(totalist, 2)
```

and changing the definition of `prefixes` to `map` over `forselection`, not `totalist`; since `compress` iterates both iterators in parallel, `tee` won't have meaningful memory overhead.

Of course, as others have noted, even moving to C, this is a linear algorithm. Ideally, you'd use something like a `collections.defaultdict(list)` to map from two element prefixes of each `list` (converted to `tuple` to make them legal `dict` keys) to a `list` of all `list`s with that prefix. Then, instead of linear search over N `list`s to find those with matching prefixes, you just do `totaldict['A', 'B']` and you get the results with `O(1)` lookup (and less fixed work too; no constant slicing).

Example precompute work:

```
from collections import defaultdict

totaldict = defaultdict(list)
for x in totalist:
    totaldict[tuple(x[:2])].append(x)

# Optionally, to prevent autovivification later:
totaldict = dict(totaldict)
```

Then you can get `matches` effectively instantly for any two element prefix with just:

```
matches = totaldict['A', 'B']
```

Comment: Indeed what fun! You get an up vote for the fun factor but please don't let this be the accepted answer! :)

Comment: @RolfofSaxony: :-) I like `itertools`; it's almost certainly not appropriate here, but the general pattern is actually a decent illustration of how to use it well for other purposes. In the OP's case, I'd almost certainly go the `defaultdict(list)` route.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony There is no need to fun, combining some functions together and doing unnecessary operations is not a correct way to go, specially for such simple task that can be done with simpler, and faster approaches.

Comment: @Kasramvd Hell's bells, I am aware of that, I simply took the answer in the spirit that it was given, as you might have been able to divine, if you looked at my last remark.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can't do this in python with a nested list. But if you are looking for an optimized approach here are some ways:

Use a simple list comprehension, by comparing the intended list with only first two items of sub lists:

```
>>> [sub for sub in totalist if sub[:2] == ['A', 'B']]
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['A', 'B', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']]
```

If you want the indices use `enumerate`:

```
>>> [ind for ind, sub in enumerate(totalist) if sub[:2] == ['A', 'B']]
[0, 1]
```

And here is a approach in Numpy which is pretty much optimized when you are dealing with large data sets:

```
>>> import numpy as np    
>>> 
>>> totalist = np.array([['A','B','C','D','E'],
...                      ['A','B','X','Y','Z'],
...                      ['A','F','T','U','V'],
...                      ['A','F','M','N','O']])

>>> totalist[(totalist[:,:2]==['A', 'B']).all(axis=1)]
array([['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
       ['A', 'B', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Also as an alternative to list comprehension in python if you don't want to use a loop and you are looking for a functional way, you can use `filter` function, which is not as optimized as a list comprehension:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x[:2]==['A', 'B'], totalist))
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['A', 'B', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']]
```

Comment: FYI, `filter` is perfectly optimized _if your predicate function is a built-in implemented in C_ (and your input is long enough); in that case, it typically runs faster than equivalent genexpr/listcomps. If it needs a `lambda` that the genexpr/listcomp could inline, it will definitely be slower, and if it's using a `def` function that can't be avoided in genexpr/listcomp, it's usually similar on performance (often slightly slower, but only just). `filter` is advanced, and it's perfectly fine to use nothing but genexpr/listcomp, but you can use it for speed ups if you understand it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yeah, I know that, but thanks for comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this.

```
>>> for i in totalist:
...     if ['A','B']==i[:2]:
...             print i
```

Comment: I wrote the answer and then I saw that he had written the same. :-)

Comment: Happens to us all!

Answer (score 0):

You imply that you are concerned about performance (cost). If you need to do this, and if you are worried about performance, you need a different data-structure. This will add a little "cost" when you making the lists, but save you time when filtering them.

If the need to filter based on the first two elements is fixed (it doesn't generalise to the first n elements) then I would add the lists, as they are made, to a dict where the key is a tuple of the first two elements, and the item is a list of lists.

then you simply retrieve your list by doing a dict lookup. This is easy to do and will bring potentially large speed ups, at almost no cost in memory and time while making the lists.

Comment: it wont always be the first two elements, it'll keep increasing as you go through the list.  Basically the list are paths, and its categorizing the paths per branch, kind of like a tree.  I'll use the if statement mentioned above.